# Looking for benchmarks on Apriltag pose estimation

Tags: pose, orientation, research, auv

we want to know if we can use Apriltags in our project for pose estimation in rather long distances and on moving target. Specifically, correcting errors of an IMU device on an autonomous vehicle.

I am looking for some evaluation reports that would provide some insight on questions like;

-at what distances can we detect tags, and what should be the resolution of these images?

-at what speeds will the tag be still detected?

And other similar potential questions that can apply to a moving distant (at max distance) target.
I have been looking at various papers. I thought I'd find some papers evaluating benchmarks, but I could not manage to find much else than comparisons between different tag libraries (which are not focusing on what we're looking for), benchmarks of close range applications, different light conditions, etc.

I'd be very happy to know if there are already some papers making this analysis.
Thank you

Comment: I don't know of any benchmarks or papers for this.  But I will mention that you may find it difficult to use Apriltags for pose estimation in outdoor settings.  Simply because the scale of things.  To use an Apriltag at a long distance requires a very large tag.  So large that it will be unusable at closer distances.  Some simple experiments should show this.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. Although I understand the idea, I was still wondering what are the limits of this. The target won't be moving very fast, neither will it be really really far. But still, it is to know how far, how fast and how accurate can it be

Comment: Not an answer, but this resource is interesting for tags benchmarking:  Experimental Comparison of Fiducial Markers for Pose Estimation   https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9213977